# Change the color in the TextBox in MaterialDesignInXAML

Tags: wpf, material-design-in-xaml

How do you change this blue color in MaterialDesignInXAML?

I try to overwrite the style but there is no option to change the color or it is under some strange name that is not in the documentation.
[image]

Comment: hint color can be changed with Foreground and line color can be changed with BorderBrush

Answer (score 1):

The colour comes from the primary accent color that has most likely been specified in the App.Xaml file.

It will look something like:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml" /
```

Changing this will change the primary color for all the application.

If you need to change just for the floating hint style, create a new style based on the floating hint style setting the Foreground and BorderBrush colors.